# GWT DataGrid does not display data when initialized while invisible

Tags: java, html, gwt, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a simple layout panel that is collapsible.  It is collapsed by default, and when I expand it after the page loads, the column headers are visible but the data rows are not.  If I set the panel to be expanded by default, then all the data in the table is visible, and remains so after collapsing/expanding again.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  I have layout panels all the way up.  I tried making the panel visible to begin with, then setting it invisible in a deferred command after setting the data provider.  However, at the time the deferred command ran, the table reported having two data rows but they hadn't displayed yet.  The panel was set invisible before the data rows ever became visible, so they *never* became visible.

I hope my description makes sense.  Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: There is a similar issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7065

Comment: Are you using a `DataGrid`. if yes you must put it into a `LayoutPanel` or `Panel` that  implements the `ProvidesResize` interface. Alterantively if you use a "normal" `Panel` you must specify the dimensions of that panel explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, user905374!  That was the problem; I had to redraw the table when I expanded it.

Comment: how do you redraw the table, exactly? Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `dataGrid.onResize()` after making the grid visible did the trick for me.

Please keep in mind that `onResize()` may need to be called from a deffered command, like this:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        view.titleGrid.onResize();
    }
});
```